# Command line tool to repair self-intersection in GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, command-line, self-intersection

I am working with [this file](https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/blob/master/ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json). Kansas seems to have a self intersection:

```
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -98.918045000000006 37.379078 at -98.918045000000006 37.379078
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -98.918045000000006 37.379078 at -98.918045000000006 37.379078
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -98.918045000000006 37.379078 at -98.918045000000006 37.379078
```

Is there a command line tool to repair this quickly and easily?

(I do not have access to QGIS.)

Comment: Regarding qgis issue, on my platform, I cannot install it in ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097177/installing-qgis-in-ubuntu-18-04-error-with-sqlite-tables-can-no-longer-use-apt
So non-qgis solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/unkink-polygon

Comment: I am not familiar with this package.  What else do I need to do to load the file or re-export it after unkinking?

Comment: Thanks, @KirkKuykendall, but I'm still not there.  If you'd prefer to answer on stackoverflow, I have a turf-specific question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548340/turf-and-unkink-polygon

Comment: I've tried both unkink and simplepolygon and can confirm they delete all the metadata and are not effective on anything as complex as actual geojson files, maybe appropriate on simple polygons.

Comment: If there's a problem with this file on github, shouldn't somebody file an issue?  https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/issues

Comment: Once I get this solved I intend to submit a pull request.

Comment: @chicks, I have filed an issue.  I would submit a pull request, but am unable myself to make the correction posted in the answer below.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/issues/2

Answer (score 3):

This is tested to work with your data and GDAL command line tools installed from OSGeo4W on Windows.

Test your data with ogrinfo. Escaped double quotes \"\" are needed because the layer name contains dot character.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from \"ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min\" where ST_IsValid(geometry)=0" ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json
```

Confirmed that there is one error

```
GEOS warning: Self-intersection at or near point -98.918045000000006 37.379078
Feature Count: 1
```

Create a new, fixed GeoJSON file by utilizing the ST_MakeValid function of SpatiaLite http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry),STATEFP10,ZCTA5CE10,GEOID10,CLASSFP10,MTFCC10,FUNCSTAT10,ALAND10,AWATER10,INTPTLAT10,INTPTLON10,PARTFLG10 from \"ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min\"" clean.json ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json
```

Check the new GeoJSON file. Ogrinfo has showed that the layer name inside GeoJSON is SELECT which is reserved keyword for SQL so it needs to be escaped.

Result:

```
INFO: Open of `clean.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 0
```

You must have GDAL that is built with new enough SpatiaLite which has the ST_MakeValid function. If you do not have such version you will see this error:

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select ST_MakeValid(geometry),STATEFP10,ZCTA5CE10,GEOID
10,CLASSFP10,MTFCC10,FUNCSTAT10,ALAND10,AWATER10,INTPTLAT10,INTPTLON10,PARTFLG10 from "ks_kansas_zip
_codes_geo.min"):
  no such function: ST_MakeValid
```

Comment: This is an amazing and thorough answer!  Do you happen to know which version of GDAL makes that possible?  I have:
`$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19`
And get this error.

Comment: Thanks, @user30184.  I'm having a lot of trouble getting a version of GDAL that allows for this, but working on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564543/making-a-docker-image-that-contains-ogr-compiled-with-modern-spatialite

Comment: user30184, any chance you can post the corrected output of your Kansas json to a pastebin while I work on compiling GDAL correctly in Ubuntu?

Comment: When compiling pay attention to SpatiaLite because that is the engine that runs MakeValid and it must be compiled with LWGEOM. Then GDAL must be compiled against this SpatiaLite.

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer, but I'm sorry I haven't accepted yet because I am unable to get these tools specially compiled on any machine I have access to.